# what does drawing samples from a density mean?

Tags: statistics

I am looking for a formal definition of "drawing samples" (or simply of "samples"), can somebody help me?

Comment: You mean drawing samples (random sampling) from the same population?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy, yes it is what I mean.

Comment: Then I think you have been answered. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are referring to random sampling.

The random variables $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are called a random sample of size $n$ from the population with pdf $f(x)$ if $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are mutually independent and the marginal pdf of each of them is exactly $f(x)$.